# How to custom input field in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Here is **yii2 code:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'category_id',
        'class' => 'mws-form wzd-validate']]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**And output HTML:**

```
<form id="cat_form" class="mws-form wzd-validate" action="/text/backend/web/index.php?r=cat%2Fcreate" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="ZHAzcENzcUI.PEofNCkdNVU7bDslOj4XIUAEFHsDNjUsRVgocUQVCw==">
    <div class="mws-form-row">
        <div class="form-group field-cat-name required">
            <label class="control-label" for="cat-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="cat-name" class="form-control" name="Cat[name]">

            <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**I want to convert HTML above:**

```
<form id="cat_form" class="mws-form wzd-validate" action="/text/backend/web/index.php?r=cat%2Fcreate" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="ZHAzcENzcUI.PEofNCkdNVU7bDslOj4XIUAEFHsDNjUsRVgocUQVCw==">
    <div id class="mws-form-row">
        <label class="mws-form-label">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="mws-form-item large">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="required" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using template. Something like this:

```
 $form->field($model, 'name',[
     'template' => '<div id="divid" class="mws-form-row">
                        <label class="mws-form-label">
                            {label}
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="mws-form-item large">{input}</div>
                     </div>'
 ]);
```