# Yii2: can I customize just the input part of an ActiveField?

Tags: php, html, forms, yii2, active-form

In [How to custom input field in yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841661/how-to-custom-input-field-in-yii2#29841858) it shows how you can change the entire `template` when using `$form->field($model, 'customer_name')` to generate the HTML for a field in an ActiveForm.

But is there a way to modify just the HTML generated by the `{input}` tag in that template?

I would like to have Yii generate all the HTML for the label and error messages, but want to generate the actual input field myself (eg. due to limitations in Yii's `dropDownList()` features).

Comment: Actually what you want to customize in {input} tag? Are you talking about the input tag attributes like id, class, data(html 5 custom variables), etc?

Comment: `ActiveField` has a public associative array called `$parts` where you can set `$yourActiveField->parts['{input}']` to whatever HTML you want

Comment: To be honest I don't understand to what limitations in Yii's dropDownList are you referring to. You can literally do everything with it, as far as you can read the documentation and follow the instructions.

Comment: @user2831723 Since `dropDownList()` uses array keys for values it's impossible to have multiple options that have the same value. I'm sure you're thinking "why on earth..." but a very valid use case is a dropdown with countries where you want to list the most common countries in the top, but ALSO list the same countries in the full alphabetical list below - in case the user doesn't realize he could just select them in the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `ActiveField` class (in my case `\yii\bootstrap4\ActiveField`) and override `render` function, then set `$this->parts['{input}'` with your custom code. e.g:

```
<?php

namespace common\widgets;

class MyCustomInput extends \yii\bootstrap4\ActiveField {
    public function render($content = null) {
        $this->parts['{input}'] = '<h3>This is my custom code for input.</h3>';

        return parent::render($content);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Remember you can get field's attributes using methods like:

```
\yii\helpers\Html::getInputName($this->model, $this->attribute)
```

**or**

```
$this->getInputId()
```

Comment: Having tested it out yet but looks like probably the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

you can use class to each field if you want

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control'])->label('Your Label',['class'=>'label-class']) ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem I note in my comment of Oct 25 '16, and is hardly a solution to the question in general.